# payola subscription with rails

Tags: ruby, payola

I am trying to implement the `payola-payment` subscription in a Rails project.

I have tried to use the gem `payola-payments` but after running `bundle`, I am facing the following error when running `rake db:migrate`:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `event_retriever=' for StripeEvent:Module
>   Did you mean?  event_filter=

I have found a solution that suggests using `gem 'payola-payments', :git => 'git@github.com:payolapayments/payola.git'`, but after that I get a migration error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #

Can any one help with this?

Comment: What version of rails and payola do you use?

Comment: Rails 4.2.6 ,payola-payments (1.5.1, 1.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Your version of payola-payment has a bug check it here :
[github.com/payolapayments](https://github.com/payolapayments/payola/issues/335)

It is suggested to replace

> gem 'payola-payments'

with

> gem 'payola-payments', :git =>
>   'git@github.com:payolapayments/payola.git'

in you Gemfile.

Comment: Thank you for your replay @andoke,but if i have tried with your suggestion and i am facing the issue like:

NoMethodError: undefined method `event_retriever=' for StripeEvent:Module